# ASP.NET : GridView in dynamics accordionPanes Ajax

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

What i'm trying to do : I have some meeting date in my database. For display this, I want make one GridView for each day. (I have several meetings by days). And after, put this gridview in accordionPane (one by day). I want put in Pane for not display a long list in the screen.

I know how make dynamics accordionPanes, I know make dynamics GridView (depends on the number of meetings). 
I know put one GridView in one accordionPane. (juste for statics one)
But I can't put dynamically GridViews in accordionPanes...

The source code of my problem :

**The way to create dynamic number of accordionPanes :**

Code Behind :

```
 For i = 1 To j
     Dim volet As New AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane
     volet.Visible = True
     volet.ID = "volet" & i.ToString
     Accordion1.Panes.Add(volet)
 Next
```

Code ASP.NET :

```
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" Width="873px" CssClass="accordion" FadeTransitions="true"   HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" RequireOpenedPane="false"    ContentCssClass="accordionContent" TransitionDuration="100">

</asp:Accordion>
```

**The way to create dynamic number of GridView :**

Code behind :

```
    For i = 1 To j
        Dim datag As New GridView
        datag.Visible = True
        datag.ID = "datag" & i.ToString
        Panel1.Controls.Add(datag) 
   Next
```

Now I try to insert GridView in accordionPanes. That's my issue.
I hope i'm clear, ask me if i'm not well expressed.

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Hello. Please consider reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions. One of things you're missing is including relevant source code that demonstrates your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer !

I missed two functions : pane.ContentContainer.Constrols.Add and pane.HeaderContent.Controls.Add.

```
    For i = 1 To j
        Dim datag As New GridView
        Dim title As New Label

        datag = GenererGridView(i) 'GridView from database

        datag.Visible = True
        datag.ID = "datag" & i.ToString
        title.Text = "datag" & i.ToString


        Dim pane As New AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane
        pane.Visible = True
        pane.ID = "pane" & i.ToString
        pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(datag)
        pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(title)
        Accordion1.Panes.Add(pane)
    Next
```